# Unity/C# Coding errors with Color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I've been troubleshooting some code for a while now. I managed to fix a problem, but that just made another, even bigger one pop up out of nowhere. Every instance of new Color (starting around line 40) springs an error: CS0246 "The type or namespace name Color could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" I'm just modding a game, doing nothing more than adding more color options for hair and eyes, but it's giving me a lot of trouble, since, while I have some experience with programming, I have none with C# or Unity.

```
if (this.Kidnapped)
    {
        this.GanguroCasualTextures = this.GanguroUniformTextures;
        this.GanguroSocksTextures = this.GanguroUniformTextures;
        this.OccultCasualTextures = this.OccultUniformTextures;
        this.OccultSocksTextures = this.OccultUniformTextures;
        this.FemaleCasualTextures = this.FemaleUniformTextures;
        this.FemaleSocksTextures = this.FemaleUniformTextures;
    }
    if (this.RightShoe != null)
    {
        this.RightShoe.active = false;
        this.LeftShoe.active = false;
    }
    this.ColorValue = new Color((float)1, (float)1, (float)1); ///**<<<---Problem starts here**
    if (this.JSON == null)
    {
        this.JSON = this.Student.JSON;
    }
    string text;
    if (!this.Initialized)
    {
        this.Accessory = UnityBuiltins.parseInt(this.JSON.StudentAccessories[this.StudentID]);
        this.Hairstyle = UnityBuiltins.parseInt(this.JSON.StudentHairstyles[this.StudentID]);
        this.Stockings = this.JSON.StudentStockings[this.StudentID];
        this.BreastSize = this.JSON.StudentBreasts[this.StudentID];
        this.HairColor = this.JSON.StudentColors[this.StudentID];
        this.Club = this.JSON.StudentClubs[this.StudentID];
        text = this.JSON.StudentNames[this.StudentID];
        this.Initialized = true;
    }
    if (text == "Random")
    {
        this.Randomize = true;
        if (!this.Male)
        {
            text = string.Empty + this.StudentManager.FirstNames[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Extensions.get_length(this.StudentManager.FirstNames))] + " " + this.StudentManager.LastNames[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Extensions.get_length(this.StudentManager.LastNames))];
            this.JSON.StudentNames[this.StudentID] = text;
            this.Student.Name = text;
        }
        else
        {
            text = string.Empty + this.StudentManager.MaleNames[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Extensions.get_length(this.StudentManager.MaleNames))] + " " + this.StudentManager.LastNames[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Extensions.get_length(this.StudentManager.LastNames))];
            this.JSON.StudentNames[this.StudentID] = text;
            this.Student.Name = text;
        }
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MissionMode") == 1 && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MissionTarget") == this.StudentID)
        {
            this.JSON.StudentNames[this.StudentID] = PlayerPrefs.GetString("MissionTargetName");
            this.Student.Name = PlayerPrefs.GetString("MissionTargetName");
            text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("MissionTargetName");
        }
    }
    if (this.Randomize)
    {
        this.Teacher = false;
        this.BreastSize = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.5f, 2f);
        this.Accessory = 0;
        this.Club = 0;
        if (!this.Male)
        {
            this.Hairstyle = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, Extensions.get_length(this.FemaleHair) - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            this.SkinColor = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Extensions.get_length(this.SkinTextures));
            this.Hairstyle = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, Extensions.get_length(this.MaleHair));
        }
    }
    if (!this.Male)
    {
        this.RightBreast.localScale = new Vector3(this.BreastSize, this.BreastSize, this.BreastSize);
        this.LeftBreast.localScale = new Vector3(this.BreastSize, this.BreastSize, this.BreastSize);
        if (this.StudentID == 32 && !this.Kidnapped && Application.loadedLevelName == "PortraitScene")
        {
            this.Character.animation.Play("f02_socialCameraPose_00");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Extensions.get_length(this.GaloAccessories); i++)
        {
            this.GaloAccessories[i].active = false;
        }
        if (this.Club == 3)
        {
            this.Character.animation["sadFace_00"].layer = 1;
            this.Character.animation.Play("sadFace_00");
            this.Character.animation["sadFace_00"].weight = (float)1;
        }
        if (this.StudentID == 13 && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CustomSuitor") == 1)
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CustomSuitorHair") > 0)
            {
                this.Hairstyle = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CustomSuitorHair");
            }
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CustomSuitorAccessory") > 0)
            {
                this.Accessory = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CustomSuitorAccessory");
                if (this.Accessory == 1)
                {
                    float x = 1.02f;
                    Vector3 localScale = this.MaleAccessories[1].transform.localScale;
                    float num = localScale.x = x;
                    Vector3 vector = this.MaleAccessories[1].transform.localScale = localScale;
                    float z = 1.062f;
                    Vector3 localScale2 = this.MaleAccessories[1].transform.localScale;
                    float num2 = localScale2.z = z;
                    Vector3 vector2 = this.MaleAccessories[1].transform.localScale = localScale2;
                }
            }
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CustomSuitorBlonde") > 0)
            {
                this.HairColor = "Yellow";
            }
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CustomSuitorJewelry") > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Extensions.get_length(this.GaloAccessories); i++)
                {
                    this.GaloAccessories[i].active = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (this.Club == 100)
    {
        this.MyRenderer.sharedMesh = this.TeacherMesh;
        this.Teacher = true;
    }
    else if (this.Club == 101)
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Student_" + this.StudentID + "_Replaced") == 0)
        {
            this.Character.animation["f02_smile_00"].layer = 1;
            this.Character.animation.Play("f02_smile_00");
            this.Character.animation["f02_smile_00"].weight = (float)1;
            this.RightEyeRenderer.gameObject.active = false;
            this.LeftEyeRenderer.gameObject.active = false;
        }
        this.MyRenderer.sharedMesh = this.CoachMesh;
        this.Teacher = true;
    }
    this.ID = 0;
    while (this.ID < Extensions.get_length(this.FemaleAccessories))
    {
        if (this.FemaleAccessories[this.ID] != null)
        {
            this.FemaleAccessories[this.ID].active = false;
        }
        this.ID++;
    }
    this.ID = 0;
    while (this.ID < Extensions.get_length(this.MaleAccessories))
    {
        if (this.MaleAccessories[this.ID] != null)
        {
            this.MaleAccessories[this.ID].active = false;
        }
        this.ID++;
    }
    this.ID = 0;
    while (this.ID < Extensions.get_length(this.ClubAccessories))
    {
        if (this.ClubAccessories[this.ID] != null)
        {
            this.ClubAccessories[this.ID].active = false;
        }
        this.ID++;
    }
    this.ID = 0;
    while (this.ID < Extensions.get_length(this.TeacherAccessories))
    {
        if (this.TeacherAccessories[this.ID] != null)
        {
            this.TeacherAccessories[this.ID].active = false;
        }
        this.ID++;
    }
    this.ID = 0;
    while (this.ID < Extensions.get_length(this.TeacherHair))
    {
        if (this.TeacherHair[this.ID] != null)
        {
            this.TeacherHair[this.ID].active = false;
        }
        this.ID++;
    }
    this.ID = 0;
    while (this.ID < Extensions.get_length(this.FemaleHair))
    {
        if (this.FemaleHair[this.ID] != null)
        {
            this.FemaleHair[this.ID].active = false;
        }
        this.ID++;
    }   
    this.ID = 0;
    while (this.ID < Extensions.get_length(this.MaleHair))
    {
        if (this.MaleHair[this.ID] != null)
        {
            this.MaleHair[this.ID].active = false;
        }
        this.ID++;
    }
    this.ID = 0;
    while (this.ID < Extensions.get_length(this.FacialHair))
    {
        if (this.FacialHair[this.ID] != null)
        {
            this.FacialHair[this.ID].active = false;
        }
        this.ID++;
    }
    this.ID = 0;
    while (this.ID < Extensions.get_length(this.Eyewear))
    {
        if (this.Eyewear[this.ID] != null)
        {
            this.Eyewear[this.ID].active = false;
        }
        this.ID++;
    }
    this.ID = 0;
    while (this.ID < Extensions.get_length(this.RightStockings))
    {
        if (this.RightStockings[this.ID] != null)
        {
            this.RightStockings[this.ID].active = false;
        }
        if (this.LeftStockings[this.ID] != null)
        {
            this.LeftStockings[this.ID].active = false;
        }
        this.ID++;
    }
    if (this.StudentID == 13 && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CustomSuitor") == 1 && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CustomSuitorEyewear") > 0)
    {
        this.Eyewear[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CustomSuitorEyewear")].active = true;
    }
    if (this.StudentID == 1 && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CustomSenpai") == 1)
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SenpaiEyeWear") > 0)
        {
            this.Eyewear[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SenpaiEyeWear")].active = true;
        }
        this.FacialHairstyle = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SenpaiFacialHair");
        this.HairColor = PlayerPrefs.GetString("SenpaiHairColor");
        this.EyeColor = PlayerPrefs.GetString("SenpaiEyeColor");
        this.Hairstyle = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SenpaiHairStyle");
    }
    if (!this.Male)
    {
        if (!this.Teacher)
        {
            this.FemaleHair[this.Hairstyle].active = true;
            this.HairRenderer = this.FemaleHairRenderers[this.Hairstyle];
            this.SetFemaleUniform();
        }
        else
        {
            this.TeacherHair[this.Hairstyle].active = true;
            this.HairRenderer = this.TeacherHairRenderers[this.Hairstyle];
            if (this.Club == 100)
            {
                this.MyRenderer.materials[0].mainTexture = this.TeacherBodyTexture;
                this.MyRenderer.materials[1].mainTexture = this.DefaultFaceTexture;
                this.MyRenderer.materials[2].mainTexture = this.TeacherBodyTexture;
            }
            else
            {
                this.MyRenderer.materials[0].mainTexture = this.CoachFaceTexture;
                this.MyRenderer.materials[1].mainTexture = this.CoachBodyTexture;
                this.MyRenderer.materials[2].mainTexture = this.CoachBodyTexture;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.Hairstyle > 0)
        {
            this.MaleHair[this.Hairstyle].active = true;
            this.HairRenderer = this.MaleHairRenderers[this.Hairstyle];
        }
        if (this.FacialHairstyle > 0)
        {
            this.FacialHair[this.FacialHairstyle].active = true;
            this.FacialHairRenderer = this.FacialHairRenderers[this.FacialHairstyle];
        }
        this.SetMaleUniform();
    }
    if (!this.Male)
    {
        if (!this.Teacher)
        {
            if (this.FemaleAccessories[this.Accessory] != null)
            {
                this.FemaleAccessories[this.Accessory].active = true;
            }
        }
        else if (this.TeacherAccessories[this.Accessory] != null)
        {
            this.TeacherAccessories[this.Accessory].active = true;
        }
    }
    else if (this.MaleAccessories[this.Accessory] != null)
    {
        this.MaleAccessories[this.Accessory].active = true;
    }
    if (this.Club < 11 && this.ClubAccessories[this.Club] != null && PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Club_" + this.Club + "_Closed") == 0 && this.StudentID != 26)
    {
        this.ClubAccessories[this.Club].active = true;
    }
    if (this.Stockings == "Loose")
    {
        this.RightStockings[0].active = true;
        this.LeftStockings[0].active = true;
    }
            if (!this.Randomize)
    {
        if (this.HairColor == "White")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color((float)1, (float)1, (float)1);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Black")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color((float)0, (float) 0, (float) 0);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Red")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color((float)1, (float)0, (float)0);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Yellow")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color((float)1, (float)1, 0.31f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Green")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color((float)0, (float)1, (float)0);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Cyan")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color((float)0, (float)1, (float)1);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Blue")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color((float)0, (float)0, (float)1);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Purple")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color((float)1, (float)0, (float)1);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Orange")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color((float)1, 0.5f, (float)0);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Brown")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.5f, 0.25f, (float)0);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Munakata")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.992f, 0.988f, 0.976f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Chisa")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.8f, 0.361f, 0.137f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Juzo")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.094f, 0.137f, 0.075f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Miaya")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.353f, 0.604f, 0.855f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Yoi")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.882f, 0.8f, 0.545f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Ruru")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.882f, 0.706f, 0.663f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Seiko")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.835f, 0.847f, 0.851f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Egg")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.765f, 0.659f, 0.62f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Kiri")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.878f, 0.847, 0.882f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Toga")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.976f, 0.945f, 0.871f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Aoi")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.431f, 0.263f, 0.239f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Fukawa")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.31f, 0.196f, 0.255f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Maizono")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.192f, 0.224f, 0.294f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Leon")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.761f, 0.239f, 0.11f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Junko")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.98f, 0.922f, 0.886f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Mukuro")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.145f, 0.125f, 0.11f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Chihiro")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.051f, 0.29f, 0.592f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Mondo")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.051f, 0.29f, 0.592f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Ame")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.133f, (float)0, 0.18f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Celes")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.094f, 0.09f, 0.09f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Hinata")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.541f, 0.447f, 0.427f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Koma")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.973f, 0.953f, 0.949f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Nanami")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.839f, 0.757f, 0.745f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Zoom")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.506f, 0.031f, 0.027f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Saionji")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.988f, 0.918f, 0.745f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Sonia")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.98f, 0.945f, 0.945f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Souda")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.9f, 0.247f, 0.541f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Akane")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.529f, 0.286f, 0.184f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Teru")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.204f, 0.11f, 0.106f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Mikan")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.012f, 0.698f, 0.388f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Kuzu")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.996f, 0.902f, 0.749f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Peko")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color((float)1, (float)1, (float)1);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Nidai")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.122f, 0.153f, 0.157f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Mita")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.886f, 0.816f, 0.769f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Noroshi")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.012f, 0.114f, 0.012f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Kiza")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.937f, 0.843f, 0.6f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Jin")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.141f, 0.082f, 0.173f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Amami")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.761f, 0.792f, 0.631f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Hitler")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.224f, 0.196f, 0.255f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Kae")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.933f, 0.855f, 0.78f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Hopebot")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.965f, 0.961f, 0.922f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Kaito")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.282f, 0.2f, 0.278f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Angie")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.961f, 0.961f, 0.945f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Maki")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.247f, 0.259f, 0.235f);
        }
        else if (this.HairColor == "Miu")
        {
            this.ColorValue = new Color(0.949f, 0.902f, 0.89f);
        }
        else
        {
            this.RightEyeRenderer.material.mainTexture = this.HairRenderer.material.mainTexture;
            this.LeftEyeRenderer.material.mainTexture = this.HairRenderer.material.mainTexture;
            this.FaceTexture = this.HairRenderer.material.mainTexture;
            this.CustomHair = true;
        }
        if (this.Hairstyle > 0)
        {
            this.HairRenderer.material.color = this.ColorValue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        float r = UnityEngine.Random.Range((float)0, 1f);
        Color color = this.HairRenderer.material.color;
        float num3 = color.r = r;
        Color color2 = this.HairRenderer.material.color = color;
        float g = UnityEngine.Random.Range((float)0, 1f);
        Color color3 = this.HairRenderer.material.color;
        float num4 = color3.g = g;
        Color color4 = this.HairRenderer.material.color = color3;
        float b = UnityEngine.Random.Range((float)0, 1f);
        Color color5 = this.HairRenderer.material.color;
        float num5 = color5.b = b;
        Color color6 = this.HairRenderer.material.color = color5;
    }
    if (!this.Teacher)
    {
        if (this.CustomHair)
        {
                if (!this.Male)
            {
                this.MyRenderer.materials[2].mainTexture = this.FaceTexture;
            }
            else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MaleUniform") == 1)
            {
                this.MyRenderer.materials[2].mainTexture = this.FaceTexture;
            }
            else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MaleUniform") < 4)
            {
                this.MyRenderer.materials[1].mainTexture = this.FaceTexture;
            }
            else
            {
                this.MyRenderer.materials[0].mainTexture = this.FaceTexture;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.RightEyeRenderer.material.color = this.ColorValue;
            this.LeftEyeRenderer.material.color = this.ColorValue;
        }
    }
    else if (this.Teacher)
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Student_" + this.StudentID + "_Replaced") == 1)
        {
            float @float = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Student_" + this.StudentID + "_ColorR");
            float float2 = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Student_" + this.StudentID + "_ColorG");
            float float3 = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Student_" + this.StudentID + "_ColorB");
            this.HairRenderer.material.color = new Color(@float, float2, float3);
        }
        this.RightEyeRenderer.material.color = this.HairRenderer.material.color;
        this.LeftEyeRenderer.material.color = this.HairRenderer.material.color;
    }
    if (this.Male)
    {
        if (this.Accessory == 2)
        {
            this.RightIrisLight.active = false;
            this.LeftIrisLight.active = false;
        }
        if (Application.loadedLevelName == "PortraitScene")
        {
            this.Character.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.93f, 0.93f, 0.93f);
        }
        if (this.FacialHairRenderer != null)
        {
            this.FacialHairRenderer.material.color = this.ColorValue;
            if (Extensions.get_length(this.FacialHairRenderer.materials) > 1)
            {
                this.FacialHairRenderer.materials[1].color = this.ColorValue;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!this.Randomize)
    {
        if (this.EyeColor != string.Empty)
        {
            if (this.EyeColor == "White")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)1, (float)1, (float)1);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Black")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)0, (float) 0, (float) 0);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Red")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)1, (float)0, (float)0);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Yellow")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)1, (float)1, 0.31f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Green")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)0, (float)1, (float)0);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Cyan")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)0, (float)1, (float)1);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Blue")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)0, (float)0, (float)1);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Purple")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)1, (float)0, (float)1);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Orange")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)1, 0.5f, (float)0);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Brown")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.5f, 0.25f, (float)0);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Munakata")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.545f, 0.467f, 0.533f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Juzo")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.827f, 0.137f, 0.518f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Chisa")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.62f, (float)1, 0.42f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Yoi")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)1, (float)0, (float)0);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Ruru")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.922f, 0.898f, 0.894f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Seiko")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.624f, 0.537f, 0.631f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Miaya")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.635f, 0.843f, 0.804f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Egg")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.957, 0.937f, 0.875f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Kiri")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.788f, 0.702f, 0.78f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Toga")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.404f, 0.525f, 0.655f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Aoi")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.298f, 0.404f, 0.498f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Fukawa")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.6f, 0.522f, 0.541f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Maizono")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.184f, 0.247f, 0.298f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Leon")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.867f, 0.878f, 0.875f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Junko")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.573, 0.612, 0.635f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Mukuro")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.533f, 0.545f, 0.612f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Chihiro")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.631f, 0.502f, 0.318f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Mondo")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.773f, 0.561f, 0.427f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Ame")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.588f, 0.463f, 0.608f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Celes")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)1, (float)0, (float)0);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Hinata")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.741f, 0.753f, 0.675f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Koma")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.722f, 0.718f, 0.702f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Nanami")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.929f, 0.792f, 0.792f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Zoom")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.494f, 0.412f, 0.392f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Saionji")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.957f, 0.804f, 0.447f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Sonia")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.408f, 0.631f, 0.745f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Souda")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.9f, 0.247f, 0.541f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Akane")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.475f, 0.451f, 0.325f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Nidai")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.71f, 0.741f, 0.773f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Teru")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)0, (float)0, (float)0);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Mikan")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.671f, 0.549f, 0.576f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Kuzu")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)1, 0.941f, 0.878f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Peko")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color((float)1, (float)0, (float)0);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Noroshi")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.078f, 0.604f, 0.263f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Mita")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.631f, 0.502f, 0.318f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Kiza")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.247f, 0.435f, 0.69f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Jin")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.604f, 0.447f, 0.6f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Amami")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.667f, 0.686f, 0.537f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Hitler")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.361f, 0.322f, 0.392f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Kae")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.769f, 0.659f, 0.702f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Hopebot")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.431f, 0.667f, 0.608f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Kaito")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.58f, 0.467f, 0.514f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Angie")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.518f, 0.584f, 0.553f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Maki")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.278f, 0.161f, 0.149f);
            }
            else if (this.EyeColor == "Miu")
            {
                this.CorrectColor = new Color(0.275f, 0.376f, 0.396f);
            }
            this.RightEyeRenderer.material.color = this.CorrectColor;
            this.LeftEyeRenderer.material.color = this.CorrectColor;
        }
    }
    else
{
    float num6 = UnityEngine.Random.Range((float)0, 1f);
    float num7 = UnityEngine.Random.Range((float)0, 1f);
    float num8 = UnityEngine.Random.Range((float)0, 1f);
    float r2 = num6;
    Color color7 = this.RightEyeRenderer.material.color;
    float num9 = color7.r = r2;
    Color color8 = this.RightEyeRenderer.material.color = color7;
    float g2 = num7;
    Color color9 = this.RightEyeRenderer.material.color;
    float num10 = color9.g = g2;
    Color color10 = this.RightEyeRenderer.material.color = color9;
    float b2 = num8;
    Color color11 = this.RightEyeRenderer.material.color;
    float num11 = color11.b = b2;
    Color color12 = this.RightEyeRenderer.material.color = color11;
    float r3 = num6;
    Color color13 = this.LeftEyeRenderer.material.color;
    float num12 = color13.r = r3;
    Color color14 = this.LeftEyeRenderer.material.color = color13;
    float g3 = num7;
    Color color15 = this.LeftEyeRenderer.material.color;
    float num13 = color15.g = g3;
    Color color16 = this.LeftEyeRenderer.material.color = color15;
    float b3 = num8;
    Color color17 = this.LeftEyeRenderer.material.color;
    float num14 = color17.b = b3;
    Color color18 = this.LeftEyeRenderer.material.color = color17;
}
    if (this.StudentID == 17)
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Scheme_2_Stage") == 2)
        {
            this.FemaleAccessories[3].active = false;
        }
    }
    else if (this.StudentID == 20 && this.transform.position != new Vector3((float)0, (float)0, (float)0))
    {
        this.RightEyeRenderer.material.mainTexture = this.DefaultFaceTexture;
        this.LeftEyeRenderer.material.mainTexture = this.DefaultFaceTexture;
        ((RainbowScript)this.RightEyeRenderer.gameObject.GetComponent(typeof(RainbowScript))).enabled = true;
        ((RainbowScript)this.LeftEyeRenderer.gameObject.GetComponent(typeof(RainbowScript))).enabled = true;
    }
    if (this.Student != null && this.Student.AoT)
    {
        this.Student.AttackOnTitan();
    }
    this.TaskCheck();
    this.TurnOnCheck();
```

Comment: You must have missed a `using` statement, which would reference the namespace in which `Color` is defined.

Comment: if you are using visual studio , just press ctrl + . ,,,, u will get the popup to incluse namespase for Color class

Answer (score 0):

First Add the reference to project **System.Drawing**
And then Add **using**

like : `using System.Drawing;`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as it just throws up the error saying Drawing doesn't exist in the namespace system. beyond that, I'm worried about referencing anything that wasn't already referenced as I'm only modding the game. I just copied and pasted some color variable lines and edited their values, nothing more. It shouldn't really be throwing up this error at all as I changed nothing in the references.Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to a **System.Drawing** since Unity has it's own `Color` defined inside the `UnityEngine`-Namespace.

So maybe look if adding this line to the top of your file is working out or at least, changing the error:

```
using UnityEngine;
```